# Background image set as no-repeat but it is repeated on server

Tags: css, background-image

I need the background of html to be an image, centered and without repeating.

If the img is smaller - it should be streched and vice versa. So the entire image should be visible.

I know, the quality of the image could be damaged, but it doesn't matter.

I tried:

```
html{
    background:url(img/back04.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat; // is ok on localhost, but on server - repeating appears !?
    background-size:cover;  //also tried
    background-size:contain; //also tried
}
```

What is the right way, pls ?

Comment: @crystal, thanks, but I cleared the cache each time, pressing `F5` in firefoks

Comment: Can you post a link to the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the following:

```
body {
    background: url(img/back04.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top center;
    background-size: auto;
}
```

*Jost

Answer (score 2):

First, verify that your server's copy matches your local copy.

Second, clear your cache. It's possible the CSS file for the server is cached and it's using an old version.

Third, are you using the same browser (and version) to test both local and server versions? CSS is always rendered client side, so if the CSS files match and you're using the same browser, you shouldn't have any discrepancies between the two versions.

Comment: I restarted firefox, and is ok now. It seams pressing F5 many times is not enough. Thanks to everyone.